# Fragment closes for unknown reason (not orientation change)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

In the below code, the fragment will close (for some reason) in the scavengerHunt method. I believe it has to do with the way I am using the valueEventListeners in my code, but I am not really sure. If I do not try to call the switch statement in these methods, the fragment will not close, but my logic won't work either. Please help, and let me know if more code is needed. I am seriously at a loss, and feel like I have tried everything with what I have, though this is obviously not the case.

```
public class scavengerHunt extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {



Button letsGo, submit;

ImageButton uploadImage;

TextView welcomeScav;

TextView instructions;

FirebaseAuth mAuth;

DatabaseReference mDatabase;

StorageReference mStorage;

private String user_id;

private String winner;

private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

private Uri imageURI;



public scavengerHunt() {

    // Required empty public constructor

}



@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scavenger_hunt, container, false);

    //initialization code

    letsGo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scav_Button);

    submit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submit_Image);

    uploadImage = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.scav_Pic);

    winner = "complete";

    welcomeScav = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.welcome_scav_Text);

    instructions = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.instruction_Scav_Text);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();





    letsGo.setOnClickListener(this);

    uploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);

    submit.setOnClickListener(this);

    submit.setClickable(false);



    return view;

}



@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.scav_Button){



        letsGo.setText("Find it!");

        letsGo.setClickable(false);

        scavengerHunt();



    } else if(v.getId() == R.id.scav_Pic){



        openGallery();

        submit.setClickable(true);



    } else if(v.getId() == R.id.submit_Image){

        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Scavenger Hunt Pictures").child(imageURI.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(imageURI).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

            @Override

            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your offering has been accepted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                letsGo.setText("Next Clue");

                letsGo.setClickable(true);

                submit.setClickable(false);

                //@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")



                //The following commented out code is a template for saving the photo URL.

                // Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                //DatabaseReference newSpeaker = mDatabase.push();

                //newSpeaker.child("name").setValue(name);

                //newSpeaker.child("bio").setValue(bio);

                //newSpeaker.child("photoURL").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());

            }

        });

    }

}



public void scavengerHunt() {

    //Get a snapshot of the database to see where the user is at on the clues.



    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override

        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //get the current value of scavenger hunt instructions

            String currentInstruction = dataSnapshot.child("Scavenger Hunt Instructions").getValue(String.class);



            //if this is the first time the user has started the scavenger hunt

            if (dataSnapshot.child("Scavenger Hunt Instructions").getValue(String.class) == null) {

                mDatabase.child("Scavenger Hunt Instructions").setValue(getInstruction("Start"));

                updateInstructions();

            } else



                //if the user has finished the hunt

                if (dataSnapshot.child("Scavenger Hunt Instructions").getValue(String.class) == "Winner") {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have completed the challenge!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //exit the fragment

                } else {



                    //this is normal operation



                    //Change the database value to the next instruction

                    mDatabase.child("Scavenger Hunt Instructions").setValue(getInstruction(currentInstruction));

                    updateInstructions();

                }

        }

        @Override

        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            //TODO: Error catch

        }

    });

//maybe something needs to go here

}



private void updateInstructions(){

    //Take a new (and freshly updated) snapshot

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override

        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //Change the instruction text to the instruction the user needs to see.

            instructions.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Scavenger Hunt Instructions").getValue(String.class));

        }



        @Override

        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            //TODO: Error catch

        }

    });

}





public String getInstruction(String current){

    String instruction = current;

    switch (current){

        case "Start":

            instruction =  "Grab a drink with the Presidents of the United States";

            break;

        case "Grab a drink with the Presidents of the United States":

            instruction = "Turns out Lincoln is a bit clingy. Go somewhere he wouldn't want to go.";

            break;

        case "Turns out Lincoln is a bit clingy. Go somewhere he wouldn't want to go.":

            instruction = "Winner";

            break;

    }

    return instruction;

}



private void openGallery(){

    //Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    //startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE);

}



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){

        imageURI = data.getData();

        uploadImage.setImageURI(imageURI);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: I should clarify that by close, I do not mean the app crashes. It works fine, but the fragment "deflates"

Comment: When the fragment closes/deflates, what is then visible--a different fragment from the same activity, a different activity, a blank screen?

Comment: A different fragment, which is the one initially loaded by the containment activity. @Bob Snyder

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code that makes any changes to the fragment manager state.  There is only a comment `//exit the fragment`.  Is the posted code what you are actually running?  How would the fragment normally be removed if the code were working correctly?

Comment: This is exactly as it is running right now. If i break the logic by not setting values, aka calling my switch statement, the fragment stays open. But the purpose of my code does not work. Normally, the fragment would only close if a user navigated away from it via back button or the nav-drawer @Bob Snyder

Comment: Is there any other place in your app where you have a listener attached for DB location 
 `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id)`.  If that were the case, setting a value in this code could trigger the processing at that other place.

Comment: @BobSnyder actually, I do, now that I think about it. How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: @Bob Snyder You sir, are a genius. In my homepage fragment (preloaded fragment) I had done exactly what you thought may have happened. I switched the listener type to single value event, and the problem was solved. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is ridiculous. It stopped being fixed. I also tried to take the entire event and make it an activity. But it still closes. I really don't understand what is going on here.